What is the proper way to derive risk definitions from utility functions?
In typical mean-variance analysis, the risk-adjusted relative value of an individual asset takes the general form
$\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}$
with further weighting and normalization depending on the particular optimization conditions.
In economics books, I have also read the suggestion that this structure is a consequence of assuming a quadratic utility function in combination with the assumption of gaussian returns. (Is that sufficient?)
I have seen some examples of expectation value computations, but I have not seen the general connection between utility functions, distributions, and the form of risk derived explicitly. What is the proper procedure to derive the form of risk-adjusted value from an arbitrary utility function and distribution? Or is there a good reference that shows this?

Related: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/79292

@RichardHardy the word you are looking for is "cross-posted".

@Giskard, right. I was in a rush and got this one a bit wrong.
